# Displaying/EnablingShield UI JavaScript chart gridlines

Tags: javascript, charts, shieldui

I am trying to figure out how one can set or enable the gridlines net for a Shield UI JavaScript chart. I have one line type graph and would like to enable the gridlines so that data becomes easier for users to read.
What I can find online is the lines stype:

```
axisX: {
plotStripColor: 'red',
plotStripDashStyle: 'ShortDashDot',
plotStripWidth: 2
}
```

but the actual result isn’t gridlines displayed as I need.

Answer (score 0):

There aren’t a classical grid lines or net as you say. But you can easily mimic one by using the minor ticks for both the X and Y axes.

```
axisY: {
minorPlotStripColor: 'red',
minorPlotStripWidth: 2,
minorTicksRepeat: 'auto',
},
```

What you can specify is the color of the lines, which in the given example is red, the line thickness, which you need to set to a value greater than 0 to be visible.
The  minorTicksRepeat property in most cases is better to be set to auto. The reason is that when set to a fixed value when the user zooms in the gridlines will become too thick and this may prevent user from easily read the graph.

Below is a code sample that you may find useful:

```
axisX: {
   },
   minorPlotStripColor: 'red',
   minorPlotStripWidth: 2,
   minorTicksRepeat: 'auto'
  },

  axisY: {
   minorPlotStripColor: 'red',
   minorPlotStripWidth: 2,
   minorTicksRepeat: 'auto',
  },
```